# How do I recover unsaved files in Gimp?

Tags: data-recovery, gimp

I was working in Gimp on a cover for my new book but before I could finish it my computer crashed and I lost all of my info. Is there any way for me to undo my computer's history and retrieve my info?

Comment: «undo my computers history» There is no "computer history", files are stored in RAM until they are saved. RAM is volatile.

Answer (score 5):

There's no easy way to recover these files.  Gimp does not save data automatically in case you forget to save.  If the application crashes, there's no way to save the data before closing the error; so, you should save all of your data after every accepted step, unless you don't care if you lose your work.

Plugin research revealed two promising links, which are both very similar.  The "linux-only" link was junk and isn't mentioned here.

Short, untested, open-source attempts (both done in python):

1. http://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-developer/11718-autosave-plugin - more officious and seemingly robust.
2. https://www.mail-archive.com/gimp-developer@lists.xcf.berkeley.edu/msg18118.html - better tabbing.

According to the author of the (2), GIMP does not want to have an auto-save feature because it makes your privacy more secure: advanced users don't have the "secret hidden tmp directory" to spy on unsuspecting beginners.

[data-privacy](/questions/tagged/data-privacy)

The more officious code says that it saves all open documents to the prescribed location every 30 minutes.  Thirty minuets is a wide gap: I want to recommend 10 seconds, but perhaps the auto-save process is processor-intensive, and it might even interrupt your work-flow.  If it does not interrupt your work flow, you should get it down to less than 5 minutes because that's about how long an old laptop battery lasts if you forget to plug it in and don't get/have battery alerts  (like in Ubuntu Mate).

[data-integrity](/questions/tagged/data-integrity)

Answer (score 1):

Backups are kept in the `/home/<user_name>/.gimp-2.8/tmp`.

Or you can to File menu to find the document history.  Go File --> Open Recent --> Document History.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help.

Comment: So there were no files in the temp folder?

Comment: yup no files...

Comment: I'd like to add that this method doesn't actually recover anything. I had an unsaved project I was working on and there was nothing in the tmp folder. The document history contained only old files I was working on. A word of advice to anyone using gimp - SAVE and save often! Although, since you already looked for recovering files, it might be too late for saving :D